# Gufw fails to control ufw

Tags: ufw, gufw

ufw is 0.34
gufw is 15.10.0

As title says it is not possible to control the active status of ufw through gufw:

1. sudo ufw status

`Status: Inaktiv`

2. start gufw, enter root passwort to authenticate. Enable the firewall. Exit gufw.
3. sudo ufw status

`Status: Inaktiv`

4. start gufw, enter root passwort, status is disabled.

If i enable the ufw with `sudo ufw enable` - starting gufw shows the status as disabled. I already tried to purge both ufw and gufw.

thx